# Dynamic row is not saved in database with Laravel Controller

Tags: mysql, arrays, laravel, dynamic, controller

I have a form in my view which asks for education qualification of students(I have provided the code below). I want the user (in my case a Student) while filling up the form should be able to dynamically add his/her subjects, total marks and marks obtained in the database table. All thing works fine when i add only one subject. But the problem comes when i try to add multiple subjects. Looking forward for a solution from you people..

This is the form in my view :

```
<form action="/edu_details" method="post">
                        @csrf
                        <div class="jumbotron">
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                  <label for="institution">Institution Last Attended</label>
                                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="institution" id="institution" value="{{old('institution')}}">
                                  @if ($errors->has('institution'))
                                    <div class="error" style="color:red;">{{ $errors->first('institution') }}</div>
                                  @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                  <label for="yop">Year of Passing</label>
                                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="yop" id="yop" value="{{old('yop')}}">
                                  @if ($errors->has('yop'))
                                    <div class="error" style="color:red;">{{ $errors->first('yop') }}</div>
                                  @endif
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                                  <label for="board">Board</label>
                                  <div class="col-sm-12">
                                      <select name="board" id="board" class="form-control">
                                        <option hidden disabled selected value> -- Select an option -- </option>
                                        <option>SEBA</option>
                                        <option>CBSE</option>
                                        <option>Other</option>
                                      </select>

                                  </div>
                                  @if ($errors->has('board'))
                                    <div class="error" style="color:red;">{{ $errors->first('board') }}</div>
                                  @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="jumbotron">
                            <table class="table table-bordered">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Name of the Subject</th>
                                        <th>Total Marks</th>
                                        <th>Marks Obtained</th>
                                        <th><a href="#" class="btn btn-info addRow">+</a></th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="text" name="subj[]" class="form-control">
                                            @if ($errors->has('subj'))
                                    <div class="error" style="color:red;">{{ $errors->first('subj') }}</div>
                                  @endif        
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="text" name="totl" class="form-control">
                                            @if ($errors->has('totl'))
                                    <div class="error" style="color:red;">{{ $errors->first('totl') }}</div>
                                  @endif        
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="text" name="obtn" class="form-control">
                                            @if ($errors->has('obtn'))
                                    <div class="error" style="color:red;">{{ $errors->first('obtn') }}</div>
                                  @endif        
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger delRow">-</a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>


                        <div class="jumbotron">
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <label for="sub_group">Group of subjects the applicant wishes to opt :</label>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="sub_group" id="sub_group" value="Major">
                                      <label class="form-check-label" for="sub_group">Major</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="sub_group" id="sub_group" value="General">
                                      <label class="form-check-label" for="sub_group">General</label>
                                    </div>                                  
                                </div>
                                @if ($errors->has('sub_group'))
                                    <div class="error" style="color:red;">{{ $errors->first('sub_group') }}</div>
                                  @endif
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-row">

                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <label for="pref1">1st Preference</label>
                                    <select name="pref1" id="pref1" class="form-control">
                                        <option hidden disabled selected value> -- Select an option -- </option>
                                        <option>Sub1</option>
                                        <option>Sub2</option>
                                        <option>Sub3</option>
                                    </select>
                                    @if ($errors->has('pref1'))
                                    <div class="error" style="color:red;">{{ $errors->first('pref1') }}</div>
                                  @endif
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                                  <label for="prefgroup1">&nbsp;</label>
                                  <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <select name="prefgroup1" id="prefgroup1" class="form-control">
                                        <option hidden disabled selected value> -- Select an option -- </option>
                                        <option>Sub1</option>
                                        <option>Sub2</option>
                                        <option>Sub3</option>
                                    </select>
                                    @if ($errors->has('prefgroup1'))
                                    <div class="error" style="color:red;">{{ $errors->first('prefgroup1') }}</div>
                                  @endif
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <label for="pref2">2nd Preference</label>
                                    <select name="pref2" id="pref2" class="form-control">
                                        <option hidden disabled selected value> -- Select an option -- </option>
                                        <option>Sub1</option>
                                        <option>Sub2</option>
                                        <option>Sub3</option>
                                    </select>
                                    @if ($errors->has('pref2'))
                                    <div class="error" style="color:red;">{{ $errors->first('pref2') }}</div>
                                  @endif
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                                  <label for="prefgroup2">&nbsp;</label>
                                  <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <select name="prefgroup2" id="prefgroup2" class="form-control">
                                        <option hidden disabled selected value> -- Select an option -- </option>
                                        <option>Sub1</option>
                                        <option>Sub2</option>
                                        <option>Sub3</option>
                                    </select>

                                  </div>
                                  @if ($errors->has('prefgroup2'))
                                    <div class="error" style="color:red;">{{ $errors->first('prefgroup2') }}</div>
                                  @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Submit Data</button>

                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".addRow").on('click', function(){
        addRow();
        return false;
    });

    function addRow(){
        var tr = '<tr>'+
                        '<td><input type="text" name="subj[]" class="form-control">@if ($errors->has('subj'))
                                    <div class="error" style="color:red;">{{ $errors->first('subj') }}</div>
                                  @endif        </td>'+
                        '<td><input type="text" name="totl" class="form-control"></td>'+
                        '<td><input type="text" name="obtn" class="form-control"></td>'+
                        '<td><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger delRow">-</a></td>'+
                '</tr>';
        $('tbody').append(tr);

        $('tbody').on('click','.delRow',function(){
            $(this).parent().parent().remove();
            return false;
        });
}
</script>
```

This is my controller's save method :

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'institution' => 'required|max:255',
            'yop' => 'required',
            'board' => 'required|max:255',
            'subj' => 'required|max:255',
            'totl' => 'required',
            'obtn' => 'required',
            'sub_group' => 'required|max:255',
            'pref1' => 'required|max:255',
            'prefgroup1' => 'required|max:255',
            'pref2' => 'required|max:255',
            'prefgroup2' => 'required|max:255',
        ]);

            //Insert student data if validated

            $edudetail = new EduDetail();
            $edudetail->user_id = Auth::user()->id;

            //$edudetail->user_id = DB::table('pictures')->where('user_id', $user_id)->value('id');
            $edudetail->institution = $request->input('institution');
            $edudetail->yop = $request->input('yop');
            $edudetail->board = $request->input('board');
            foreach($request->get('subj') as $subj) {
                $edudetail->subj[] = $subj;
                $edudetail->save();
            }
            $edudetail->totl = $request->input('totl');
            $edudetail->obtn = $request->input('obtn');
            $edudetail->sub_group = $request->input('sub_group');
            $edudetail->pref1 = $request->input('pref1');
            $edudetail->prefgroup1 = $request->input('prefgroup1');
            $edudetail->pref2 = $request->input('pref2');
            $edudetail->prefgroup2 = $request->input('prefgroup2');

            $edudetail->save();

            return redirect('/student_dox_upload')->with('success','Education Details saved.');

    }
```

I have tried to see if the values are passed as arrays in case of the subject field using print_r method.. And the values are seen in arrays... that's working fine.. but when i go to save only the last record of the dynamic row gets added.. For example if i add 3 subjects English, Maths and Science.. I want all 3 subjects to be added in a column but only Science is getting added.. Any help is appreciated..

Comment: what you want to store in subj field?
$subj json?

Answer (score 1):

Like the bottom, make a fillable for the input values ​​inside the model

```
$fillable=['institution',...];
```

Rules in the file in the request on the path
app \ Http \ Request
Define in a file
And then save the data in the form below

```
public function store(NewServiceRequest $request,Variable $variable,Variable $variable){
        $variable->fill($request->only($variable->getFillable()));
        $variable->save();
        $variable->variable()->save($variable);
        .
        .
        .
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did exactly what you said and it worked for the subjects field... But when I tried to implement your solution with the totl field and obtn field i got an error..

I tried this :

```
$edudetail = new EduDetail();
            $edudetail->user_id = Auth::user()->id;

            //$edudetail->user_id = DB::table('pictures')->where('user_id', $user_id)->value('id');
            $edudetail->institution = $request->input('institution');
            $edudetail->yop = $request->input('yop');
            $edudetail->board = $request->input('board');
            $edudetail->subj = json_encode($request->get('subj'));
            $edudetail->totl = json_encode($request->get('totl'));
            $edudetail->obtn = json_encode($request->get('obtn'));
            $edudetail->sub_group = $request->input('sub_group');
            $edudetail->pref1 = $request->input('pref1');
            $edudetail->prefgroup1 = $request->input('prefgroup1');
            $edudetail->pref2 = $request->input('pref2');
            $edudetail->prefgroup2 = $request->input('prefgroup2');

            $edudetail->save();
```

I got this error :

Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (22007)
SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '["100","100","100","100"]' for column `cas_db`.`edu_details`.`totl` at row 1 (SQL: insert into `edu_details` (`user_id`, `institution`, `yop`, `board`, `subj`, `totl`, `obtn`, `sub_group`, `pref1`, `prefgroup1`, `pref2`, `prefgroup2`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (1, Little Flower School, 2004, CBSE, ["Science","Maths","Computer","English"], ["100","100","100","100"], ["72","76","80","78"], General, Sub2, Sub1, Sub3, Sub2, 2019-07-28 11:21:24, 2019-07-28 11:21:24))